# view object not accessible in setOnClickListener

Tags: android, android-view

I have initialize object in class like following

```
View popupView; //This is global
```

I have created View object in onCreate() method like following

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_filter_form, null);
```

I want to access view object in setOnClickListener like following

```
popupView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

But above line gives an error **" popupView cannot be resolved to a type "**. Please help.

Full Code as following

```
public class Myclass1 extends Activity 
{
TextView tv_addiction_name, tv_today, tv_yesterday, tv_this_week, tv_this_month, tv_total;
ImageView iv_back, iv_filter;
int year, month, day;
int placeData;
Boolean state = false;
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateListener;
SQLiteDatabase database;
int cat_id = 0;
View popupView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_addiction_details);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_filter_addiction_form, null);
    popupView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String cat_name = intent.getStringExtra("cat_name");
    tv_addiction_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewAddictionDetails);
    tv_addiction_name.setText(cat_name);

    tv_total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_total);
    tv_today = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_today);
    tv_yesterday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_yesterday);
    tv_this_week = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_this_week);
    tv_this_month = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_this_month);

    iv_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewAddictionDetailsBack);
    iv_back.setClickable(true);
    iv_back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v)
                                        {
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(AddictionDetails.this, StartActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                        }
                                    }
                                );

    iv_filter = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewAddictionDetailsFilter);
    iv_filter.setClickable(true);
    iv_filter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v)
                                        {
                                            if(state == false)
                                            {
                                                state = true;
                                                popupView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // Getting error on this line.
```

Comment: Remove `static` , Just use as simple, `View popupView = null;`

Comment: u will need to call `setVisibility` for Views inside inflated activity_filter_form layout instead of `popupView` . like `(LinarLayout)popupView.findViewById(R.id.layout_id).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: @user370305 : tried but not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the member popupView is not visible in anonymous class OnClickListener. You should try to acces it via MyClass1.popupView.

Comment: i can not access MyClass1 too in OnClickListener

Answer (score 0):

Try this I hope this will help to you..

```
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_filter_form, R.id.layout_id,true);
```

Comment: have you put your layout id to replace null?

Comment: How can i get **R.id.layout_id** ??

Comment: RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);

Answer (score 0):

define the `popupView`  variable inside `onCreate()` and make it `final`. You will be able to access it inside the `onClick()` method then.